# Java/javac not found opensuse

Tags: java, opensuse, path-finding

I have installed java jdk-1-7-0 through yast and zypper.  I keep seeing things about changing the path but nothing is specific enough for me to fix my issue, I am new to openSUSE and from what I have read there are problems with openSUSE and Java. Their website talks about using rpm for downloading but when I do my results are different than their expected results.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain *how* your results are different and exactly what the problem is. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: I don't know where you heard that there are problems with Java in OpenSuSe, I have never had any issues. Please provide more details: what is "expected results", and what is "my results"? Also, it might be that you have accidentally installed more than one version of Java in Yast, that can indeed cause conflicts.